# What's the importance hierarchy of an updating notification Android app?

Tags: android, lifecycle

If an app generate a notification, and keep its builder in a singleton and schedule a timer or handler to update its content, after user clicks the back button and exit the app, what will be its importance hierarchy for Android system?

Is it still a normal background process which will be killed when system needs more memory or a more important process since [app standby document](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#understand_app_standby) says

> The app generates a notification that users see on the lock screen or in the notification tray.

then won't it enter app standby mode?

If it has higher hierarchy, what's its position in the importance hierarchy?